# Proof by Induction - Doubt at exemple

Tags: summation, fractions

I was just studying the 'Method of Mathematical Induction' by I. S. Sominskii when this example came on:
$$(\dots)$$

$$S_k=\frac{1}{(1)(2)}+\frac{1}{(2)(3)}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}+\dots+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k}{k+1}$$

$$(\dots)$$

So my problem is that I can't understand how to get to that result.
Probably partial fractions???

Could someone please, explain me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: To clarify, when you write $\dfrac 1{1.2}$, do you mean $\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2}$

Comment: Yes! That's correct, is 1 TIMES 2, so on. I've edited it.

Comment: $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$

Comment: @zkutch but how the summation get to there? I still don't get it.

Comment: Since you are studying the "Method of Mathematical Induction", this can be proven by induction: for the induction step,

$$\begin{align*}
S_{k+1} &= S_k + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&= \frac{k}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&= \frac{k(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&= \frac{k+1}{k+2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Linho. Wrote explanation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using from comment
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\dots+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\\
=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}=  \\
=1-\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{k}{k+1}$$

Comment: OMG! Thank you very very much. Now I get it. I wasn't 'canceling' the fractions with partials. So at the finish my calculations was a totally mess.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, @Linho. Now You can choose and mark answer, which satisfies your more.

Answer (score 0):

We have the definition: $\displaystyle\forall k\in\Bbb N^+~.~S_k:=\sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n\,(n+1)}$

$$S_k=\dfrac 1{(1)(2)}+\dfrac{1}{(2)(3)}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(k)(k+1)}$$

We have a hypothesis that: $\forall k\in\Bbb N^+~.~ S_k=\dfrac{k}{k+1}$

Proof by mathematical induction:

> If the hypothesis holding for any positive natural number $k$ *does* imply that it holds for $k+1$, and the hypothesis *does* hold when $k=1$ , then the hypothesis *will* hold for any positive natural number.

$$\begin{split}&S_1=\dfrac 1{1+1}&&\text{by the definition}\\&\forall k\in\Bbb N^+~.\left[ S_{k}=\dfrac{k}{k+1}\to S_{k+1}=\dfrac{k+1}{(k+1)+1}\right]&\qquad&\bigstar\text{ show this}\\\hline\therefore~ &\forall k\in\Bbb N^+~.~ S_k=\dfrac{k}{k+1}\end{split}$$

---

Well, by definition $S_{k+1}=S_k+\dfrac{1}{(k+1)\,(k+2)}$ . So you just need to show $$\dfrac{k}{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{(k+1)\,(k+2)}=\dfrac{k+1}{k+2}$$

Algebra kadabra!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation about the next step! Have a nice day.